# api platform with graphQL support

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

Just started to work with api platform with graphQl support enabled. If I understand correctly with graphQl I don't need to create routes like we need with REST, the endpoints are created in the frontend from the Model schemas.

But what if I have a method which had some logic in it and I need to run that code? If I dont have a route I can't execute that. What can I do than?

Thanks for the answers in advance.
Br

Comment: According to [this](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/), and according to [this](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#operations) it basically because they limit it to basic CRUD operations on singular and collections. I think the only answer is to create a REST endpoint for those.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that by using [custom queries](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#custom-queries) to fetch data or [custom mutations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#custom-queries) to post/put/delete data in REST terms.

You question implies you want to have a custom mutation, according to the docs this would work like this:

Create your resolver:

```
<?php

namespace App\Resolver;

use ApiPlatform\Core\GraphQl\Resolver\MutationResolverInterface;
use App\Model\Book;

final class BookMutationResolver implements MutationResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Book|null $item
     *
     * @return Book
     */
    public function __invoke($item, array $context)
    {
        // Mutation input arguments are in $context['args']['input'].

        // Do something with the book.
        // Or fetch the book if it has not been retrieved.

        // The returned item will pe persisted.
        return $item;
    }
}
```

then use this custom mutation as following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Resolver\BookMutationResolver;

#[ApiResource(
    graphql: [
        // Auto-generated queries and mutations
        'item_query',
        'collection_query',
        'create',
        'update',
        'delete',

        'mutation' => [
            'mutation' => BookMutationResolver::class
        ],
        'withCustomArgsMutation' => [
            'mutation' => BookMutationResolver::class,
            'args' => [
                'sendMail' => ['type' => 'Boolean!', 'description'=> 'Send a mail?' ]
            ]
        ],
        'disabledStagesMutation' => [
            'mutation' => BookMutationResolver::class,
            'deserialize' => false,
            'write' => false
        ]
    ]
)]
class Book
{
    // ...
}
```